# error javascript in ie8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I downloaded  the tooltip from this site: http://projects.sebastianhelzle.net/jquery.smallipop/index.html
Are loaded perfectly in all browsers updated.
I have a problem with Internet Explorer 8, is loaded only the first tooltip, others are not.
This is the code used:

```
<img src="img/fitness.png"/>
<a  href="#" class="smallipopright"
  style="filter: alpha(opacity:0); background:blue; opacity:0; width: 454px; height: 52px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 269px; margin-left:-906px; z-index:1;"> 
    <span class="smallipopHint">
      <img class="floatRight inline" src="img/Body_Building.jpg" alt="Body Building" height="100" width="85"/>
          <h5>Body Building</h5>
            <p>
            L’allenamento per un corpo da urlo!
            <br>Costruite muscolo vero!
            Eliminate grasso corporeo!
            </p>
    </span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.smallipopright').smallipop({
      preferredPosition: 'right',
      theme: 'black',
      popupOffset: 10,
      invertAnimation: true,
      triggerOnClick: true
      });
    </script>
  </a>
<a  href="#" class="smallipopright" style="filter: alpha(opacity:0); background:blue; opacity:0; width: 454px; height: 52px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 321px; margin-left:-906px; z-index:1;"> 
    <span class="smallipopHint" href="#">
      <img class="floatRight inline" src="" alt="" height="" width=""/>
        <h5>Fitness</h5>
          <p>
          Una verità uguale per tutti non esiste,
          <br>ad ognuno l’allenamento in base alla<br>conformazione fisica.
          <br>La connessione<br>mente-muscolo esiste davvero!
          </p>
    </span>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.smallipopright').smallipop({
      preferredPosition: 'right',
      theme: 'black',
      popupOffset: 10,
      invertAnimation: true,
      triggerOnClick: true
      });
    </script>
  </a>
```

Comment: Potential answerers benefit from knowing what is the error and what have you tried on your. "Please debug my code" questions are usually not welcome in the community and not helpful to other users.

Comment: when i open the site with IE8 i get this error: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<img src="img/fitness.png"/>
<a  href="#" class="smallipopright"
style="filter: alpha(opacity:0); background:blue; opacity:0; width: 454px; height:    52px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 269px; margin-left:-906px; z-index:1;"> 
<span class="smallipopHint">
  <img class="floatRight inline" src="img/Body_Building.jpg" alt="Body Building" height="100" width="85"/>
      <h5>Body Building</h5>
        <p>
        L’allenamento per un corpo da urlo!
        <br>Costruite muscolo vero!
        Eliminate grasso corporeo!
        </p>
</span>

</a>
<a  href="#" class="smallipopright" style="filter: alpha(opacity:0); background:blue; opacity:0; width: 454px; height: 52px; border: 0; position: absolute; top: 321px; margin-left:-906px; z-index:1;"> 
<span class="smallipopHint" href="#">
  <img class="floatRight inline" src="" alt="" height="" width=""/>
    <h5>Fitness</h5>
      <p>
      Una verità uguale per tutti non esiste,
      <br>ad ognuno l’allenamento in base alla<br>conformazione fisica.
      <br>La connessione<br>mente-muscolo esiste davvero!
      </p>
</span>

</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.smallipopright').smallipop({
          preferredPosition: 'right',
          theme: 'black',
          popupOffset: 10,
          invertAnimation: true,
          triggerOnClick: true
      });
  });
</script>
```